# Is this a good design of creating a pythonic 'add-on'?

Tags: python

In the following piece of code I 'add on' a class to some base class. The idea is to use this pattern to 'add on' classes as needed, but I am not sure if this is good pythonic code or not...

```
class Driver(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var=1

class Extra(object):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def foo(self):
        print self.driver.var

driver = Driver()
driver.extra = Extra(driver)
driver.extra.foo()
```

The general idea is to use this pattern in `py.test` so I can pass the object easily around to other functions in the tests like

```
foo(driver)
```

instead of

```
foo(driver, extra1, extra2, extra3)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Python classes are not relational database tables. You have to manually create the  bidirectional links which seems hard to maintain.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by that...

Comment: @Alex is there a reason that `extra` attribute is bound to `driver`?

I think you can still write `extra = Extra(driver)`. This pattern is typical. I'm not sure of the necessity to chain it to `driver`.

Comment: I want to chain the add-ons to driver, so I can pass it easily to a function like: `foo(driver)` instead of `foo(driver, extra1, extra2, extra3)`...

Comment: Does `Extra` hold data of its own or is it just a wrapper around some functionality?

Comment: Its just some wrapper around the basic class' functionality...

Comment: And why do you want to restrict that to some driver instances only?

Comment: Actually every driver instance will have all 'add-ons'. But depending on the tests that are added, more 'add-ons' might be required.